# unit test in grails: "missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getMetaClass()"

Tags: unit-testing, grails, easymock

I m using grails 2.2, and i try to test a class with easymock.
My class is called Task, and contains a service called Service, that i would like to mock in my test.

```
void test(){
    Task task = new Task()
    Service service = createMock(Service.class)
    task.service = service

    expect(service.call(10)).andReturn(true)
    replay(service)

    task.execute()
}
```

And here is the code of the method call:

```
boolean call(Long id){}
```

But, systematically, when i run the test in my IDE or with the test-app command provided by grails), i have the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call getMetaClass()
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:43)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:73)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:92)
at com.Service$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fa4a7672.getMetaClass(<generated>)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.checkCall(PogoMetaClassSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:36)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.myApp.Test.test(MyTest.groovy:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:22)
... 18 more
```

It seems i have an error in my test, but i can t see what i m doing wrong.
Can you help me ?

Comment: What is in line 86 of `MyTest`?

Comment: the line 56 is the recording of the call method : expect(service.call(10)).andReturn(true)

Comment: can you try renaming method `call()` in service class to something else? For example: `blahCall()` and then test.

Comment: i named the method "call" to simplify the question. with another name, the error still appears

Comment: @OutOfBound I have deleted my unhelpful answer. Having done some reading, I think the extra method call is being made on the proxy that is sitting behind the actual Grails Service. Any chance you can try creating the mock as a nice mock and see what happens? `Service service = createNiceMock(Service.class)`